# Persist Entity with relations in another EntityManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have several EntityManagers declared like this :

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   %db_default_driver%
            host:     %db_default_host%
            port:     %db_default_port%
            dbname:   %db_default_name%
            user:     %db_default_user%
            password: %db_default_password%
            charset:  UTF8
        sync:
            driver:   %db_solarsync_driver%
            host:     %db_solarsync_host%
            port:     %db_solarsync_port%
            dbname:   %db_solarsync_name%
            user:     %db_solarsync_user%
            password: %db_solarsync_password%
            charset:  UTF8
        master:
            driver:   %db_master_driver%
            host:     %db_master_host%
            port:     %db_master_port%
            dbname:   %db_master_name%
            user:     %db_master_user%
            password: %db_master_password%
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                FOSUserBundle: ~
                SolarWebUserBundle: ~
                SolarWebSolarSalesBundle: ~
                SolarWebSolarAdminBundle: ~
        sync:
            connection:       sync
            mappings:
                FOSUserBundle: ~
                SolarWebUserBundle: ~
                SolarWebSolarSalesBundle: ~
                SolarWebSolarAdminBundle: ~
                SolarWebSolarSyncBundle: ~
        master:
            connection:       master
            mappings:
                FOSUserBundle: ~
                SolarWebUserBundle: ~
                SolarWebSolarSalesBundle: ~
                SolarWebSolarAdminBundle: ~
```

Each connection represents one database.

And a "Devis" Entity. There are 2 OneToOne relations with DevisDonnesTranches and DevisOptions.
It is declared like this in Devis.php

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SolarWeb\SolarSalesBundle\Entity\DevisDonneesTranches")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="donnees_tranches_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $donnees_tranches;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SolarWeb\SolarSalesBundle\Entity\DevisOptions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="options_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $options;
```

For replication purpose, I have to fetch a Devis and its relations from 'sync' and persist them in 'master'.
But when I do so, I get a

```
Notice: Undefined index: 000000005846b3b000000000cfe7c32f in /srv/http/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2219
```

I think it is because of the OneToOne relationship. Because when I $devis->setDevisOptions(null) and $devis->setDevisDonneesTranches(null), the Devis is persisted in 'master'. But without any relation.

So I tried to persist DevisOptions and DevisDonneesTranches in 'master', and I get a

```
Class Proxies\SolarWebSolarSalesBundleEntityDevisOptionsProxy is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

So, I guess I missed some points about the EntityManagers when trying to persist an entity from an entitymanager to another one.
Is there any advice, or even good practice to do so ?

Thank you.

Comment: Entities loaded from an EntityManager (EM) will not be "known" to other EM's even when those EM's are the same DB because Doctrine remembers entities via object references (and not by something simple like primary key). I don't believe there's an "easy" way to copy the entity across EM's. Maybe you need to setup proper replication in your DB server and not do this in code.